# Macbook Pro Freezes when waking from sleep/hibernation

Tags: performance, startup

When I open my MacBook Pro after it has been closed (usually for more than 1 hr) I get a slow response.

One of the following happens:

1. I hear a mechanical startup sound, and grey screen appears.

   [image]

   Then once that loads I get my login screen, but it's frozen. Mouse won't move and can't type. If I don't touch anything then the screen will turn off after 1 minute. Then if I do anything, touch the trackpad, or the keyboard, it will open like it should. Instantly to the login screen and I can type my password no problem.

   This takes about 2–3 minutes to get up and running.
2. The screen is opened and the computer goes straight to the frozen login screen.
3. Screen does not respond. Stays black. I have to hold down the power button to do a hard restart.
4. This happened for the first time yesterday. The grey screen shifted to a darker grey and took me to a welcome page where I could choose the language and then it had options for a forgotten password etc.

MacBook Pro 13″, Mid 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe indicates a failing disk. Here are 3 methods to fix that.

If you can start in Safe Mode then use Disk Utility to try to repair it.

Alternatively use the <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> to boot in to the recovery mode and use the Disk Utility

If that did not work start in Single user mode and run `fsck -fs` to try to repair it.

See this Apple KB article here: https://support.apple.com/kb/HT203176